# Understanding why $\int_{\cos(k)/\sqrt{1+\cos^{2}(k)} \leq y} \frac{dk}{2\pi} = 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\big(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\big)$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $dk$ be the Lebesgue measure on the unit circle, I was having trouble understanding why

> $\int_{\cos(k)/\sqrt{1+\cos^{2}(k)} \leq y} \frac{dk}{2\pi} = 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\big(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\big)$

Comment: If you integrate out the $k$ variable, then why do you still have $k$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: Maybe $k$ isn't so important on the right hand side, I really just want to understand the left hand side. It looks like we are taking the measure of $\{ k  \in [0,2\pi): \cos(k)/\sqrt{1+\cos^{2}k} \leq y \}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the circle

Comment: What I am trying to say is that there is a typo in your question.

Comment: Ok, it's actually from a physics paper, but I can change it.

Comment: How does $y$ play any role in this?

Comment: So we are computing the CDF of something, $y$ is a fixed number.

Comment: Again, what I mean is that your right hand side should depend on $y$ not $k$.

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo, I checked the published version of the paper and I was going off the preprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
\int_{[0, 2\pi)\cap \{\cos(k)/\sqrt{1+\cos^2(k)}\le y\}} \frac{dk}{2\pi} =&\ 2 \int_{[0, \pi)\cap \{\cos(k)/\sqrt{1+\cos^2(k)}\le y\}} \frac{dk}{2\pi}\\
=&\ \int_{[0, \pi)\cap \{ \arccos(y/\sqrt{1-y^2})\le k \le \pi\}} \frac{dk}{\pi} \\
=&\ \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{\arccos(y/\sqrt{1-y^2})}d k = \frac{1}{\pi}\left( k \bigg|^\pi_{\arccos(y/\sqrt{1-y^2})}\right) \\
=&\ 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)
\end{align}